# Trying to display Business Hours on my website - jQuery Opening Times by day of the week, date, and open hours

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to display business opening times by day of the week (Monday to Sunday, date (16 Feb), and open hours (0:00am - 0:00pm).

The issue I am having is Sunday's date is displaying incorrect, however, Monday to Saturday the dates are correctly displayed.

Here is a image of the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1U0w.png

What am I dong wrong, can someone please help?

```js
const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];
//TODAY
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = today.getMonth(); //String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var d = today.getDay();
//set lable today on table for today 
var currentDay = '.day' + d.toString() + 'Name';
jQuery(currentDay).html("Today");
jQuery('.day' + d.toString()).removeClass("gpGrn");

//set label for Tomorrow
if (currentDay == 6) {
  jQuery(".day0Name").html("Tomorrow");
} else {
  var tomo = '.day' + (d + 1).toString() + 'Name';
  jQuery(tomo).html("Tomorrow");
}
//set all days

var x = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

  var date1 = new Date();
  if (i == 0 && d != 0) {
    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + (i + (d - 1)));
  } else if (i < d) {
    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() - (d - i));
  } else if (i > d) {
    date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + (i - d));
  }


  //date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + (x));
  var mth = monthNames[date1.getMonth()];
  var dt = String(date1.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  jQuery(".day" + i.toString() + "Date").html(dt + " " + mth);
  //alert(i.toString());
  //x++;
}
```

```css
.day td {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.day td {
  border: none;
}

.dt {
  text-align: center;
}

.tm {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="openingHrs ">
  <tr class="day day1 gpGrn bordercol">
    <td class="day1Name nm" style="width:33.3%">Monday</td>
    <td class="day1Date dt" style="width:33.3%"></td>
    <td class="tm" style="width:33.3%">9:00am - 5:30pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=" bordercol gpGrn day day2 ">
    <td class="day2Name nm">Tuesday</td>
    <td class="day2Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 5:30pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bordercol gpGrn day day3 ">
    <td class="day3Name nm">Wednesday</td>
    <td class="day3Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 5:30pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gpGrn day day4 bordercol">
    <td class="day4Name nm">Thursday</td>
    <td class="day4Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 8:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gpGrn day day5 bordercol">
    <td class="day5Name nm">Friday</td>
    <td class="day5Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 9:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gpGrn day day6 bordercol">
    <td class="day6Name nm">Saturday</td>
    <td class="day6Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 5:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gpGrn day day0 ">
    <td class="day0Name nm">Sunday</td>
    <td class="day0Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">10:00am - 5:00pm</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems like you've overcomplicating this. Do the hours change per day of the month? Can you not just have a static list by day?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, my client doesn't want it as a static, that would be the easier option. They wanting the day to change with the dates. It's a pain in rear end lol

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your title should be a cler, specific question about your challenge and not a project summary.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is more complex than it needs to be. A simplified version would be to calculate the nearest past Monday to start the week, then iterate 6 times to get the dates for the remaining days of that week.

Also note that you can us `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` to format your dates for multiple cultures/languages without needing an explicitly translated array.

Here's a working example with the above changes made:

```js
const compareDates = (source, compare) => source.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) === compare.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const addDaysToDate = (date, days) => {
  var startDate = new Date(date);
  return new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + days));
}

const dt = document.querySelectorAll('.dt');
const today = new Date();
const tomorrow = addDaysToDate(today, 1);
const dateFormat =   new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { day: '2-digit', month: 'short' });

var prevMonday = new Date();
prevMonday.setDate(prevMonday.getDate() - (prevMonday.getDay() + 6) % 7);

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  const date = addDaysToDate(prevMonday, i);
  const isToday = compareDates(today, date);
  const isTomorrow = compareDates(tomorrow, date);
  dt[i].textContent =
    isToday ? 'Today' :
    isTomorrow ? 'Tomorrow' : dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

```css
.day td {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.day td {
  border: none;
}

.dt {
  text-align: center;
}

.tm {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="openingHrs ">
  <tr class="day day1 gpGrn bordercol">
    <td class="day1Name nm" style="width:33.3%">Monday</td>
    <td class="day1Date dt" style="width:33.3%"></td>
    <td class="tm" style="width:33.3%">9:00am - 5:30pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=" bordercol gpGrn day day2 ">
    <td class="day2Name nm">Tuesday</td>
    <td class="day2Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 5:30pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bordercol gpGrn day day3 ">
    <td class="day3Name nm">Wednesday</td>
    <td class="day3Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 5:30pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gpGrn day day4 bordercol">
    <td class="day4Name nm">Thursday</td>
    <td class="day4Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 8:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gpGrn day day5 bordercol">
    <td class="day5Name nm">Friday</td>
    <td class="day5Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 9:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gpGrn day day6 bordercol">
    <td class="day6Name nm">Saturday</td>
    <td class="day6Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">9:00am - 5:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gpGrn day day0">
    <td class="day0Name nm">Sunday</td>
    <td class="day0Date dt"></td>
    <td class="tm">10:00am - 5:00pm</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```